# Query search android studio, problemas em listar dados do firebase

Tags: query, android-studio, firebase, algoritmo-de-busca, firebase-database

Alguém poderia me ajudar? O app recupera os dados da `child("grupos")` na depuração, mas quando eu coloco o nó, por exemplo, `child("grupos").child("nome")`, o aplicativo da *crash* e nem na depuração da para ver se está recuperando. O que estou fazendo errado?

Database 
https://ibb.co/C1Gy8gs

DEBUG 
https://ibb.co/6b8Whw3

Erro usando `child("groupos").child("nome");`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference
    .activity.SalasActivity$1.search(SalasActivity.java:86)
    .activity.SalasActivity$1.access$000(SalasActivity.java:56)
    .activity.SalasActivity$1$1.onQueryTextChange(SalasActivity.java:78)






public class SalasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference ref;
ArrayList<Deal> list;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_salas);

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("grupos").child("nome");
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(ref != null){
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        list = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                        list.add(ds.getValue(Deal.class));
                        }
                        AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(list);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
                    }
                    if (searchView != null){
                        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                                search(s);
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                private  void  search(String str){
                    ArrayList<Deal> myList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Deal object : list){
                        if (object.getNome().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())){
                            myList.add(object);

                        }
                    }
                    AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(myList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(SalasActivity.this,databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Deal.class
erro
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xxx.chat, PID: 11966
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type .activity.Deal

```
    public class Deal {
    private String nome;
    private String id;
    private String membros;

    public Deal() {
    }

    public Deal(String nome, String id, String membros) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.id = id;
        this.membros = membros;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMembros() {
        return membros;
    }

    public void setMembros(String membros) {
        this.membros = membros;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Marc!

Para recuperar o `nome`, você precisará da `key` do grupo. Ficaria mais ou menos assim, por exemplo, para obter o nome do grupo

```
mDatabaseRef.child("grupos")
            .child("-L_KE54XVwBMans6Bh6") // Key do grupo
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                       String nome = dataSnapshot.getValue().child("nome");
                     }
                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                 }
             });
```

Sempre que um grupo é adicionado na árvore, é adicionado com uma `key`. Quando precisar recuperar informações dele, precisará saber sua `key`.

EDIT 1: você precisa adicionar os dados recuperados ao seu `ArrayList`;

EDIT 2: o que acontece é que você tenta recuperar um campo que não é do tipo que está definido na sua classe `Deal`, provavelmente o atributo `membro`. No *database*, ele aparenta ser um ser um `array` de objetos ou um tipo de lista (`ArrayList` ou `List`). Acredito que a para o seu propósito, seu *database* não está estruturada de forma correta.

**Sugestão**

Como seu projeto ainda está no início, sugiro que modifique essa estrutura e separe a lista de membros da `child` grupos. Quando for criar a lista de membros, use a `key` da `child` grupos ao qual ela pertence, por exemplo, para o primeiro grupo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que a `key` da `child`  é a mesma do grupo ao qual ele pertence, como sugerido. Veja também, a `key` de cada membro, pode ser sua própria identificação dentro do *database*. Então quando quiser recuperar a lista de membros, faça dessa forma

```
mDatabaseRef.child("membros")
                .child("-L_KE54XVwBMans6Bh6") // Key do grupo
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                         if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                mMembros.add(snapshot.getValue(Membro.class);
                            }
                         }
                     }
                     @Override
                     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                     }
                 });
```

Há algumas vantagens nisso: fica mais fácil obter a lista de membros, garante que um mesmo membro não seja adicionado duas ou mais vezes no mesmo grupo e você não vai precisar iterar pelos grupos para obter os membros.

Essa reestruturação é a melhor solução para seu problema, pois é mais escalonável. Considere antes de criar as outras parte do seu projeto, ler a documentação do *Firebase Database* de [como estrutura o banco de dados](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data?hl=pt-br) (é um leitura rápida, mas que vai esclarecer alguns pontos importantes).

Espero que isso resolva seu problema!

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo recuperou, mas meu arraylist continua zerado segue uma imagem do debug  https://ibb.co/6m4dBqs

Comment: estou tendo esse erro agora, com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type .activity.Deal vou atualizar a pergunta com a classe Deal se puder me ajudar ficaria grato

Comment: @Marc editei minha resposta com as repostas